# runtime error in a function copying from string to allocated memory

Tags: c, memcpy, strlen, calloc

I have some second thoughts about the following C puzzle question. I'm curious what more experience C programmers may think... Have a look at the sample code:

```
char * strdup (const char * s) { 
    char * buf;
    int len;
    assert(s != NULL);
    len = strlen(s);
    buf = (char *) calloc(len + 1, sizeof(char)); 
    memcpy(buf, s, len); 
    return buf;
}
```

The proposed implementation of strdup() above contains a runtime error that may NOT appear consistently with each invocation. Which one of the following accurately describes this error?

The possible answers to this one are:

1 The arguments to calloc() do not cause enough memory to be allocated for storing the contents of s.

2 If memory is scarce, calloc() may fail and return NULL. The code does not anticipate this condition.

3 memcpy() may corrupt data if used to copy ASCII strings.

4 buf is never NUL-terminated, and therefore cannot be used by C library functions affecting strings.

5 The function returns a pointer to dynamic memory. This practice should be avoided and always constitutes a memory leak.

What I've thought is that **the correct answer is 2** but it is more because the other answers seem incorrect to me than because answer 2 is the immediate right one.

- answer 1 seems incorrect as calloc reserves enough memory (len+1) to end the string appropriately,
- I dont know anything about what is written in answer 3,
- answer4: memcpy copies the content of s to buf leaving the last byte equal to 0 (copies len bytes, note that previos call to calloc filled the last byte with 0). Therefore, this answer is incorrect,
- answer 5: ?

What do you think?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: My answer would be 2 as well. Because `calloc` does return NULL if it fails, and you should never call `memcpy` with a NULL pointer. 1 and 4 are simply incorrect. No idea what they mean by 3 "memcpy() may corrupt data if used to copy ASCII strings". 5 may be argued for, but then, there's not much choice in C!

Comment: strlen returns a size_t but len is a int? btw, why don't use strcpy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct answer is 2 & 5.

`#2` because memory allocation functions can fail and you must check their return values.

`#5` because, unless you document the fact that your function dynamically allocates returned buffer caller cannot know that they have to free the returned buffer.

`#1` is not correct because, as you rightly said `calloc` allocates memory required by string + extra byte required for `NULL` termination.

`#3` is not correct because it is not true, `memcpy` simply copies data from source to destination. It is not affected by what is stored in that memory.

`#4` is not correct, because `calloc` zeroes out the allocated memory.

Comment: I would take the 5 incorrect, just because of the "always" word.

Comment: @lerosQ: I will take it as correct because unless your interface documentation states the dynamic memory allocation, it is *"always"* incorrect to do so. Since there is no mention of documentation I gather it is a valid statement.

Comment: Yes, the wording in #5 sounds like you should always avoid dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: @MrLister: You should never unless you tell the user of your function about it or the better option is to let the user pre-allocate the buffer and pass it as an argument.If you have the freedom of designing your own interface, second option is always better.

Comment: Well in my book, if you have an "unless", then there is no place for an "always". But anyway that practice should be avoided.

Comment: It does talk about an implementation of [`strdup`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strdup.html), which is documented to allocate memory for the returned string.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker: I assume the discussion is not limited by the fact that the name of the function matches a standard library function.

Comment: I'm simply basing myself on two parts of the puzzle : "Which *one* of the following accurately describes this error" indicates there's only one right answer, and "proposed implementation of strdup()" indicates the function has been documented (and since such documentation is absent from the question, a reasonable assumption is that they refer to the POSIX `strdup`)

Comment: @SanderDeDycker: In counter argument, *Proposed implementation* wouldn't apply if the discussion is about `strdup` from the standard library.

Comment: Well, somebody has to implement it ;) Otherwise we wouldn't have it available for use on our favorite platforms. And both for the initial implementation and any future alterations, one can *propose* an *implementation*. It can even just be a *proposed implementation* as a thought exercise (which is the more likely scenario here).